# Flowbite dropdown not working when using with *ngFor in the Angular

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive, flowbite

Flowbite dropdown not working when using with *ngFor in the Angular. I tried to pass dynamic and unique id to these items but still not working:

- button id
- button data-dropdown-toggle
- dropdown menu div id
- ul aria-labelledby

```html
<div
  class="mb-3 flex items-center justify-between py-2 px-4 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow hover:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
>
  <p class="text-sm">{{ task.text }}</p>
  <div>
    <button
      [id]="'dropdownButton_' + task.id"
      [attr.data-dropdown-toggle]="'task-detail-dropdown_' + task.id"
      class="inline-block text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5"
      type="button"
    >
      <span class="sr-only">Open dropdown</span>
      <svg
        class="w-5 h-5"
        aria-hidden="true"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 16 3"
      >
        <path
          d="M2 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3Zm6.041 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM14 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3Z"
        />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <!-- Dropdown menu -->
    <div
      [id]="'task-detail-dropdown_' + task.id"
      class="z-10 hidden text-base list-none bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700"
    >
      <ul class="py-2" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'dropdownButton_' + task.id">
        <li>
          <a
            href="#"
            class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white"
            >Edit</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="#"
            class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-red-600 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white"
            >Delete</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/luckydevboy/taskify)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in StackBlitz? Meanwhile, I don't see any of your code that applies `*ngFor*. Besides, please do not use [tag:angularjs] tags as Angular and AngularJS are different frameworks. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/luckydevboy/taskify @YongShun

Comment: you likely need to add javascript to add/remove the tailwind class `hidden`

Comment: It works without *ngFor @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is as reported in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/579).

**Approach 1**

You may implement and apply the `@FlowBite` decorator as in this [comment](https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/579#issuecomment-1641203418).

**Approach 2**

You need to follow the [instruction](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/angular/#install-flowbite) to work with dynamic components.

> Update the app.component.ts file to use the initFlowbite function to enable the interactive components via data attributes:

```
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

export class TaskComponent {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    initFlowbite();
  }
}
```

Comment: You may refer to this forked repository for the changes: https://github.com/yongshun950824/taskify/tree/yongshun950824/patch-68230

Comment: Unfortunately, the last task's dropdown won't open! @YongShun

Comment: Sorry not notice about it. Use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.